# How to find ther number of edges in a OBJ file?

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, autodesk, wavefront

I have an obj file and I want to retrieve information about this file, I can get the number of triangles and Vertices using Autodesk Meshmixer but how to get the number of edges ? Can I use the Euler formula vertices + faces = edges + 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on several variables. Does your application count shared edges as one edge or multiple edges (you're using 3ds max tag where it's 50-50, editable mesh takes them as multiple edges and editable poly as one edge), does the exporter force triangles or keeps quads/polygons, and as you only know the number of faces and the number of verts, is the mesh watertight (i.e. no open edges/borders)? To illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that it counts shared edge as one edge , and the exporter forces triangles

Comment: Shared edges means that unless the exporter limits the exported objects to watertight meshes only (so you cannot export a single face or a plane etc.), there's no way of telling the number of edges just from the number of verts and number of faces.